# How to count similar values in csv and import into asp.net (C#) gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have CSV with something like this (uses pipe delimiter)

```
a|45
b|45
c|55
d|65
e|45
```

What I want do is display in gridview, the number of entries, something like

```
45-3
55-1
65-1
```

How can i achieve this?

I am doing this right now

```
//  get all lines of csv file
    string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Test.csv"));

    // create new datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // get the column header means first line
    string[] temp = str[0].Split('|');

    // creates columns of gridview as per the header name
    foreach (string t in temp)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(t, typeof(string));
    }

    // now retrive the record from second line and add it to datatable
    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] t = str[i].Split('|');
        dt.Rows.Add(t);

    }

    // assign gridview datasource property by datatable
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;

    // bind the gridview
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

It prints out all the data from the csv right now

Comment: Are you sure that's a CSV file?

Comment: Can you show some actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Test.csv"))
               .Select(s => s.Split('|')[1].Trim())
               .GroupBy(s => s)
               .Select(s => new 
                {
                    Value = s.Key,
                    Count = s.Count()
                })
               .ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Will get you:

```
Value   Count
 45       3
 55       1
 65       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Test.csv")).GroupBy(line => new { l = line.Split('|')[1] }).Select(a => new { text = a.Key.l + "-" + a.Count() }).ToArray();
```